# $resource is not changing the id of the url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-resource

I am in trouble to change the id param of a URL passed to `$resource`. Apparently the value isn't changing to the correct value that it recive from `Resource.get(id:$routeParams.id)`, even when I put a fixed value `(Resource.get(id:1))`, resulting in the following error:

> TypeError: encodeUriSegment is not a function

When I change the id param of the URL for a fixed value `(baseURL+'client/1')`, it works.

This is my font:

**app.js**
    'use strict';

```
angular.module('serviceOrder',['ngRoute','ngResource'])
    .config(function ($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
        /*$locationProvider.html5Mode({
            enabled: true,
            requireBase: false
        });*/

        $routeProvider.when('/clients', {
            templateUrl: 'views/clients.html',
            controller: 'ClientController'
        });

        $routeProvider.when('/newclient',{
            templateUrl: 'views/client.html',
            controller: 'NewClientController'
        });

        $routeProvider.when('/editclient/:id',{
            templateUrl: 'views/client.html',
            controller: 'EditClientController'
        });

        $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/clients'});
    });
```

**controler.js**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('serviceOrder')
.controller('EditClientController',['$scope','$routeParams','clientService',
        function ($scope,$routeParams,clientService) {
            $scope.message = 'Loading ...';
            $scope.client = {};
            $scope.phone = {id:'',brand:'',model:'',state:'',esn:''};
            debugger;
            clientService.getClients().get({id:$routeParams.id})
                .$promise.then(
                function (response) {
                    $scope.client = response;
                },function (error) {
                    $scope.message = 'Error: ' + error;
                }
                );

    }]);
```

service.js
    'use strict';

```
angular.module('serviceOrder')
    .constant('baseURL', 'http://localhost:8080/service-order-rest/rest/')
    .service('clientService',['$resource','baseURL',function ($resource,baseURL){
        this.getClients = function () {
            return $resource(baseURL+'client/:id',null,{'update':{method:'PUT'}});
        };
    }]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your param defaults are not being configured properly. To achieve this, according to [`$resource`'s docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource), you must especify the pattern of your API method that will receive params like `{ id: '@id' }` instead of `null`.

```
$resource(baseURL + 'client/:id', //url
    { id: '@id' }, // parameters
    {
        'update': { method: 'PUT' } // methods
    });
```

Comment: `return $resource(baseURL+'client/:id',
                    {id:'@id'},
                    {'update':{method:'PUT'}
                    });`

Comment: I can't edit my comment, but I want to say that I've tried this, and it isn't working yet.

Comment: @Mc.Queide have you reproduced this bahaviour?

Comment: Yes, I have reproduce.

Comment: @Mc.Queide are you able to provide a working fiddle?

Comment: folow my code in github, https://github.com/mcqueide/service-order/tree/master/service-order-angular

Comment: @Mc.Queide yet, I'm not able to simulate this, but it could be caused by the `id` passed on route parameters being `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: I think this to, but I have put a fixed value when I call Resource.get(), `Resource.get(id:1)` to try this. And even so, it isn't working.

Comment: @Mc.Queide Also, I've seen on your `bower.json` that your `angularjs` version differs from the `angular-resource` version. Consider using `"angular" : "^1.5.7"` instead so that you avoid conflicts.

Comment: now I'm having another problem, now with the routes, I will try to resolve this, if I can't, I will search about this. By the way, thank you very much, for your help. I can't give you a vote up because I don't have sufficient score, but I'm very grateful.

Comment: @Mc.Queide not a problem, at all. I think is that, version conflict, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

We have a bug here :

```
return $resource(baseURL+'client/:id',{id: youridhere} ,{'update':{method:'PUT'}});
```

Comment: I have changed to `return $resource(baseURL+'client/:id',{id:'@id'},{'update':{method:'PUT'}});` but it isn't working yet.